# How to create a dictionary by iterating over a list, with same key multiple values?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary, dataframe

I have the output from `df` command to check my filesystem. I got it from os.command and then added it to a list. Now I am realing line by line and want to create a dictionary as I need to send the response as a json later.

```
Filesystem          Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xxxx/yyy       9.8G  3.2G  6.1G  35% /
tmpfs               32G     0   32G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sss            247M  106M  129M  46% /boot
/dev/aaa/ccc        1.5G  205M  1.2G  15% /home
/dev/bbb/ddd        2.2G  152M  2.0G   8% /opt
```

How I want is:

```
{
Filesystem:/dev/xxxx/yyy
{ 
Size: 9.8G
Used:
Avail:
Use%:
Mounted on:
}
Filesystem:tmpfs
{ 
Size: 
Used:
Avail:
Use%:
Mounted on:
}
Filesystem:/dev/sss
{ 
Size: 
Used:
Avail:
Use%:
Mounted on:
}
}
```

My code as of now is :

```
output = os.popen('df -Ph')
df_contents=output.readlines()
for line in df_contents:
    print(line)
```

I want to understand if this is possible, since I have same key with different values and if so what is the best way to do this in python?

Comment: Your output is not a valid Python literal, it is unclear what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, no, you can't have different keys of the same name in the same dictionary.  However, if you're grouping everything by `FileSystem` anyway, you could just have your dictionary's keys be the values themselves of `FileSystem`, in which case your dictionary will look like this:

```
{ '/dev/xxxx/yyy': {'Size': '9.8G', 'Used': '3.2G', ... }
  'tmpfs: {'Size': '32G', 'Used': '0', ... }
   ... and so on.
}
```

Assuming each line in `df_contents` has the data separated by whitespace (and not necessarily tabs), and there is no whitespace within any of the values themselves, then you can just use `.split()` to split each line.

```
var_keys = ['Size', 'Used', 'Avail', 'Use%', 'Mounted on']
mydict = {}
for line in df_contents:
    # This next command breaks the line into a list, 
    # like ['/dev/xxxx/yyy', '9.8G', '3.2G', '6.1G', '35%', '/']
    values = line.split()
    mydict[values[0]] = dict(zip(var_keys, values[1:]))
```

Comment: It worked like a charm in one attempt. And yes, it makes sense to use the filesystem values as keys. Thanks for the solution. Accepting right away.

Comment: One little change here, values[1:6] instead of values[1:5] to get the 'Mounted on' value.

Comment: values[1:5] will give till value[4] and not the 5th one. However, values[1:] is fine too. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Gonna be something pretty close to this:

```
headers = [
  'Size',
  'Used',
  'Avail',
  'Use%',
  'Mounted',
]

lines = [line.strip().split() for line in df_contents if line.strip()]

{line[0]: dict(zip(headers, line[1:])) for line in lines}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can go with compat and df.to_json

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO
df_contents = pd.read_csv(StringIO(output.read()), sep = '\t')
df_contents.to_json(orient='table')
```